# How to fill color in bar chart with different bar having different colors?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I tried to use this code:

```
public class BarChartCustomizer extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer 
    public void customize(JFreeChart jFreeChart, JRChart jasperChart) 
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) jFreeChart.getCategoryPlot()
                .getRenderer();

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.cyan);
```

But it fills all bar color as cyan..

Comment: Can you please post your jrxml file?

Comment: you can create different series for individual bars. For value you can create variables. And using series colors you can specify colors for individual bar series. I did one of the report in this way, so I am suggesting you this way.

Comment: Your chart only has one series and that series color is cyan. If you want different bars to be different colors, a different series will need to be used to represent each bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use Jasper Reports library to create custom reports and finally you can add that created report into your java code to visualization.Following [link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-charts-and-subreports-jaspersoft-studio) give you some idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StackBar Chart, assign a value to the columns you want to appear and the other leaves with value 0, this will allow you to associate a color to the different series you have.

Create a SubDataset with the values separately.

```
-- Example in PostgreSQL
SELECT
 month
,(CASE WHEN row_number() over () > 1 AND row_number() over () < (count(*) over () - 1) THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS value
,(CASE WHEN row_number() over () = 1 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS first
,(CASE WHEN row_number() over () = count(*) over () THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS last
FROM vw_datachart
WHERE id = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what you are trying to achieve.

```
public class BarChartSample extends Application {
    final static String austria = "Austria";
    final static String brazil = "Brazil";
    final static String france = "France";


    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String,Number> bc = 
            new BarChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");       
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");       
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 25601.34));
//        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 20148.82));
//        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 10000));
//        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 35407.15));
//        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 12000));      

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("2004");
//        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 57401.85));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 41941.19));
//        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 45263.37));
//        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 117320.16));
//        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 14845.27));  

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("2005");
//        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 45000.65));
//        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 44835.76));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 18722.18));
//        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 17557.31));
//        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 92633.68));  

        Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
        bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> Your chart only has one series and that series color is cyan. If you
>   want different bars to be different colors, a different series will
>   need to be used to represent each bar.

[image]

> This site is helpful with barcharts: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/bar-chart.htm